# Web API Security-How to protect student ID when you have to send it via http

Tags: jquery, web-services, security

I have a WebAPI and I need to send an unique key that identifies the student id. Since I am using an ajax call, I have to send that unique student id to the service to get that student's records. This is visible to the end user via view source or developer tools in some way (either a hidden html field or the url post or get parameter). 
How can I prevent a student from view-sourcing my scheme and changing the id to another student and thus accessing someone else's data? Or closely related looking at the history and finding out the last student's id and accessing their history?

Comment: Initially, when the student is created, you should salt that mofocka with something like SHA1 or MD5. Then you can use the salted value in the element and reference it directly. If the student can change the MD5 or Sha1 and get another student, you must have a whole-shit-ton of students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never trust the client.  Never send sensitive data over an unencrypted link or to an insecure (untrusted) client.  In your scenario you will need to maintain a server side session capable of managing it's own security.e.g. only accessing the correct student details.  Give that session a unique, non-contiguous key, salt that key and use that as a session id returned to the client.  When the client undertakes further interactions use that token to identify the session but never trust it to verify all further interactions.  This is the job of your session.

- [Starting point for Defensive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming),
- [Defend Your Apps and Critical User Info with Defensive Coding Techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163883.aspx),
- [Developing Web Services Applications](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/redp4884.html?Open)

Answer (score 1):

You should encrypt any sensitive information that goes over the wire using well-known algorithms like 3DES or Rijndael and decrypt at the endpoints.

Comment: Yo dawg. I heard you like encrypting, so I put 3des inside of Rijndael on an MD5 value so you can encrypt while you're encrypting the encrypted data.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone using your WebAPI should have to provide log on credentials first. You should be storing the information like student id's on the server side using session variables and a session cookie. If the user tells you they are student 'XYZ' you should be able verify it on the server side before handing back any other information. Also, note that this still isn't  secure, as a malicious user can still snoop on the packets a client is sending to a server, and use that to impersonate your user. A properly secured system should be using HTTPS for all traffic containing sensitive data.